# How to set the color to the select box and its border in firefox?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, drop-down-menu

I want to set the color to the border of the select box and its contents.
I am able to see the color to the border of select box in IE. But I cannot see the border color in Firefox.

I want to set the color to the border to the select box items also.
Is there any way to do this ?

To set the border color to the IE I am using the following code base.

```
select {
 border-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: It will be great if you provide the code which work on IE.

Comment: @Salil: Please check the post again.

Comment: I think IE take default border color blue, when you change it to "border-color:red;" it it work or not.

Comment: @Salil: Noway. The default color to the SELECT box and the TEXT box is black.

Answer (score 1):

In firefox, you need to specify the full border:

for instance:

```
border:1px solid blue;
```

Problem, however, is that it'll then render the select box in the old non-native blocky style.  It's rather ugly compared to the native rendering (especially on Mac OS X).

Also -- for color:

```
color:green;
```

And background color:

```
background-color:gray;
```

Comment: That works on FF, Chrome, and IE8, but NOT IE7 or lower.  Maybe that's what he meant?